# Calculus exercise (James Stewart book) : Volume of a box

Tags: calculus, recreational-mathematics, volume

I'm learning calculus but I'm very stuck in this exercise.

[image]
[Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDTKg.png)

I know that the volume is :
2HL + 2HW + LW (only LW because open top).

Thanks to the exercise we know that:

W = 12 - 2x
L = 20 - 2x
H = x

Consequently I replaced the values:

2x(20 - 2x) + 2x(12 - 2x) + (20 - 2x)*(12 - 2x)

= -4x^2 + 240

**My function is f(x) = -4x^2 + 240**

However, **I don't understand why in the correction it is written 4x^3 - 64x^2 +240x ?**

[Correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6IZ7.png)

Comment: The width of the box is $20-2x$, the other width is $12-2x$ and the height is $x$, thus the volume is $V(x)=(20-2x)(12-2x)x=(240-64x+4x^2)x$. Seems to work.

Comment: Recall that a volumen needs of  $x^3$ (three dimensions) and you have got $x^2$ then area (two dimensions).

Comment: Note that the formula you used (2HL + 2HW + LW) was for the *surface area*, not for the volume. The volume is HLW.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment shows, the length of the horizontal box's basis is $\;20-2x\;$ and the vertical one is $\;12-x\;$, so the base's area is $\;(20-2x)(12-2x)=4x^2-64x+240\;$, and since the height is $\;x\;$ your volume function is

$$f(x)=x(4x^2-64x+240)=4x^3-64x^2+240x$$

Answer (score 0):

You haven't calculated the volume of the box, but the surface of the cutout.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/714310)

Comment: @Nizar: Read the question carefully: the OP doesn't ask for the volume, he asks why his result does not coincide with the one in the book. Therefore, this post does answer the question.